# Unable to run graphics.h program in windows shell

Tags: c, bgi

I'm trying to run this program on through `gcc` on Windows shell.
GCC version that I'm using:

```
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
int main(){
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    line(150,150,450,150);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

At first, it was giving me this error:

```
fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory
     #include<graphics.h>
```

Then I added the `graphics.h` file to my `gcc` directory.
But now it is showing this error:

```
Gph.C: In function 'int main()':
Gph.C:5:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
                        ^
C:\Users\simple\AppData\Local\Temp\cchdXkih.o:Gph.C:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `initgraph'
C:\Users\simple\AppData\Local\Temp\cchdXkih.o:Gph.C:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `line'
C:\Users\simple\AppData\Local\Temp\cchdXkih.o:Gph.C:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `closegraph'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone suggest an alternative way to run my program? I've already tried running it on Visual Studio and Online Compilers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CodeBlocks IDE for it. [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/include-graphics-h-codeblocks/).

Or you can also use TurboC++ but you will have to make a minor change to your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
int main(){
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
    line(150,150,450,150);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

An advantage of using TurboC++ is that you will not have to download any extra files to run your `graphics.h` programs unlike other IDE like CodeBlocks or DevC++.

Comment: I already tried using Turbo c++ but it gives no output. I'll try with your code.

Comment: The link you posted is not a link to Code::Blocks as implied by the preceding text; it is a link to an article on how to use WinBGIm with Code::Block.  The solution is therefore not to use Code::Blocks, but rather to use WInBGIm - WinBGIm works with MinGW/GCC which he was already using, Code::Blocks is not necessary to this solution.  Moreover because the answer in in the link and not in this answer, it is a "link-only" answer and therefore discouraged on SO.  The answer needs to stand alone, supported by links, but not dependent on them.

Comment: And the suggestion to use the antique Turbo C++ is just bad advice.

Comment: Turbo C++ is downright ancient at this point. There are people on this site who have finished university and are younger than it. Please, let it go. It served us well in the 1990s but is just a relic now.

Comment: I'm cool with using TurboC++. Actually my university is still using TurboC++ for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to

```
fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory
     #include<graphics.h>
```

graphics.h is not a standard library.  It refers in this case to the [WinBGIm](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/) library that implements the Borland MS-DOS BGI API using the Windows GDI API.

Moreover header files in general are not libraries, which is why you get "undefined reference" errors - you have to link the library itself, not just include the header.

For:

```
Gph.C:5:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
```

The warning is perhaps clear, but it is doubtful that you intended C++ compilation given that you tagged the question [C], but you have named your source with a .C instead of .c extension (lower-case).  That causes C++ compilation as specified at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html.  The fact that the argument is not declared `const` in graphics.h is a problem of const-correctness where C is more permissive that C++.  It is perhaps surprising the author has not fixed it.  If you do use C++ compilation, then you would need to `const_cast` it.

So you need to:

- download the WInBGIm library,
- add the necessary include file path compiler switch (`-I`) to our build command
- add the necessary linker switches to your build command to link the library,
- change the filename extension to lower-case .c for C compilation.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for a great explanation. I'll make the changes in my home computer. Actually I was getting this error while I was in my uni so I couldn't download anything on university computers.